# Is is possible to generate static Git credentials for HTTPS connection to AWS CodeCommit using only the CLI and not the AWS Console?

Tags: aws-codecommit

I want to generate a git username/password for CodeCommit, I see how to do that from the AWS Web Console , but is there a way to do it via the aws cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aws iam create-service-specific-credential`, documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-service-specific-credential.html)

```
 aws iam create-service-specific-credential --service-name codecommit.amazonaws.com --user-name xxxxxx
{
    "ServiceSpecificCredential": {
        "CreateDate": "2022-10-28T12:19:19+00:00",
        "ServiceName": "codecommit.amazonaws.com",
        "ServiceUserName": "xxxxxx-at-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
        "ServicePassword": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
        "ServiceSpecificCredentialId": "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL",
        "UserName": "xxxxxx",
        "Status": "Active"
    }
}
```

The `ServiceUserName` can be used as git user and `ServicePassword` can be used as git password.